# ScoreLabel in Swift for Game not working right

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I'm trying to get a score label to work in my game, I want the score to increase by 1 whenever "hero" passes a "wall" I've got it so the number 0 is up top in the corner where the score is, and when I start the game it counts up but way too fast. As in the wall won't even be coming yet and I'm already at Example: 67 points. Any suggestions on how I can get it so that when the hero passes the wall it gives 1 point or if the wall gets to point x I get 1 point?

It's kind of like flappy bird!

Here is the code

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {


var movingGround: CSMovingGround!
var hero: CSHero!
var cloudGenerator: CSCloudGenerator!
var wallGenerator: CSWallGenerator!
var wall: CSWall!
var scoreLabel = UILabel()
var score = Int()
var isStarted = false

var heroCategory: UInt32 = 1<<1
var wallCategory: UInt32 = 1<<2
var groundCategory: UInt32 = 1<<2
var invisCategory: UInt32 = 1<<3
let walls = CSWall()



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    /*
    let backgroundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "background.png")
    let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(texture: backgroundTexture, size: view.frame.size)
    backgroundImage.position = view.center
    addChild(backgroundImage)
    */



    // add ground
    movingGround = CSMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, kCSGroundHeight))
    movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)

    self.addChild(movingGround)

    // add hero
    hero = CSHero()
    hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
    hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: hero.size)
    hero.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    hero.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    hero.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = heroCategory | wallCategory
    hero.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory | groundCategory
    self.addChild(hero)
    hero.breathe()


    // add cloud generator
    cloudGenerator = CSCloudGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    cloudGenerator.position = view.center
    addChild(cloudGenerator)
    cloudGenerator.populate(7)
    cloudGenerator.startGeneratingWithSpawnTime(5)

    // add wall generator

    wallGenerator = CSWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
    wallGenerator.position = view.center
    wallGenerator.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect : wallGenerator.frame)
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    wallGenerator.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = wallCategory | heroCategory | invisCategory
    wallGenerator.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = invisCategory

    self.addChild(wallGenerator)


    let ground1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 20))
    ground1.position = view.center
    ground1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground1.size)
    ground1.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ground1.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
    ground1.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    self.addChild(ground1)

    let ground2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, 20))
    ground2.position = CGPointMake(284, 98)
    ground2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground2.size)
    ground2.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ground2.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
    ground2.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = groundCategory | heroCategory
    self.addChild(ground2)

    let ground3 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(20, 500))
    ground3.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    ground3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground3.size)
    ground3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = invisCategory
    ground3.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = invisCategory | wallCategory
    ground3.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
    self.addChild(ground3)

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 20))
    scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0)
    scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(scoreLabel)


}


func start() {
    isStarted = true
    hero.stop()
    hero.startRunning()
    movingGround.start()

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if !isStarted {
        start()
        score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = "0"
        wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(0.5)
    } else {
        hero.flip()
    }


}

func addScore() {
    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == invisCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == wallCategory || firstBody.categoryBitMask == wallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == invisCategory {
        self.addScore()
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(heroCategory)) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & UInt32(wallCategory)) != 0 {
        wallGenerator.removeFromParent()
        let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let scene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: false)
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
    }


}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

}
}
```

Code to CSWall (Wall)

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class CSWall: SKSpriteNode {

let WALL_WIDTH: CGFloat = 30.0
let WALL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50.0
let WALL_COLOR = UIColor.blackColor()

override init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: WALL_COLOR, size: CGSizeMake(WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT))
    startMoving()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func startMoving() {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: 1)
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
}


}
```

Code that Generates the Wall in game

```
import SpriteKit

class CSWallGenerator: SKSpriteNode {

var generationTimer: NSTimer?

func startGeneratingWallsEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
    generationTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(seconds, target: self, selector: "generateWall", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}

func generateWall() {
    var scale: CGFloat
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(2)
    if rand == 0 {
        scale = -1.0
    } else {
        scale = 1.0
    }

    let wall = CSWall()
    wall.position.x = size.width/2 + wall.size.width/2
    wall.position.y = scale * (kCSGroundHeight/2 + wall.size.height/2)
    wall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: wall.size)
    wall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    addChild(wall)

}

}
```

Comment: You are allocating a brand new wall every time `update` runs. I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: @Paulw11 do you mean in my gamescene under the override func update()?

Comment: Yes, you are allocating a new wall via `CSWall()`

Comment: @Paulw11 I have took that command out completely :"let wall = CSWall()" it still isn't working when the wall passes the x position (68) I've tried to do < 68 and > 68 still can't get it to work

Comment: @Paulw11 I have edited my first "code" (Gamescene) if you check it out up top as I added scorelb() to my Update and added a func above that, It still isn't working for some reason though

Comment: @Paulw11 walls is CSWalls still as In the top next to all of the var's I added `let walls = CSWall()`

Comment: Nope, can't see it. You need to be checking the walls created by your generator anyway.  What I would do is create an invisible scoring edge and when the wall contacts the scoring edge, add one to the score.

Comment: @Paulw11 How would i go about checking the walls that are created by the generator?

Comment: See my edit to my previous comment

Comment: @Paulw11 I have tried to create a long invisible Wall kind of thing right in front of the hero so when the wall hits that wall it ups the score, but that didn't work when I tried that either.

Comment: That is what you need to do.  Make sure you add the physics and set the collision mask.

Comment: @Paulw11 What kind of command would I use to make it so it added a score when the two collide?

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey Paul, I have updated the code above in my question. Could you help me understand why it isn't adding + 1 to the score when the wall collides with the invisible wall? You told me to create one which I did and I've tried to get it to work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried enabling `showsPhysics` on your `SKScene` to confirm that everything is where you intend it to be?

Comment: @Paulw11 I just turned it on, and they all have physics around them, I'll show you a picture : http://oi61.tinypic.com/2irn3pe.jpg    I'm trying to get that long wall "ground3" in front of my guy to count + 1 when the wall (Palm Trees) collide with it like you suggested, did I type my code wrong or something, because the Hero is able to collide with the Palm trees but nothing happens when the palm tree collides as it doesn't add +1 like it is suppose to

Comment: You need to set the `contactTestBitMask` for the invisible wall and the palm tree - the contactTestBitMask should be the category of the other object.

Comment: @Paulw11 I've added the contactTestBitMask for the invis wall and the palm tree which I put it the category of the other object that still doesn't work as in making the score go up :( I updated the code above to show you! The long wall is "ground3" and the palm tree is "wallGenerator"

Comment: You can't rely on the first object being the invisible wall and the second being the other wall in `didBeginContact`.  The objects could be in either order.  All you need to check is if one of the objects is the invisible wall - because you know only one other type of object can contact it.  Set a breakpoint in this method and check what is happening

Comment: @Paulw11 I just updated the code above in they didBeginContact during the first object section to check for both. I'm really new to coding, How would I go about making it so if anything contacts the invisible wall then it updates the score +1?

Comment: You can just say `if firstBody.categoryBitMask == invisCategory || secondBody.categoryBitMask == invisCategory {
        self.addScore()
    }` - but set a breakpoint in this method or use NSLog.  Is it being called when the walls collide?

Comment: @Paulw11 ok I put your code into what I had mine, and I added "println("Object has been collided")" above self.addScore() to see if any outputs would come out when something collided, but nothing popped up in the output menu as in it never said Object has been collided when I could see objects colliding with the wall

Comment: @Paulw11 am I missing something in my code somewhere? I have to be doing something wrong

Comment: @Paulw11 Fixed the problem and got it to work! :)